# xdvipdfmx out of memory problem

Tags: xetex, latexmk, xdvipdfmx

I am generating a pretty big PDF file (around 1.6 GB) using xelatex:

```
latexmk -xelatex MyBigTexFile
```

All seems to go well, but the problem is that when xdvipdfmx is executed I get an out of memory error:

```
xdvipdfmx -o "MyBigTexFile.pdf"  "MyBigTexFile.xdv"

xdvipdfmx:fatal: Out of memory - asked for 2896286 bytes
No output PDF file written.
```

I tried to execute manually the xdvipdfmx cutting the output file in two by selecting different page ranges:

```
xdvipdfmx -s 1-7000 -o "MyBigTexFilePart1.pdf" "MyBigTexFile.xdv"
xdvipdfmx -s 7000-10000 -o "MyBigTexFilePart2.pdf" "MyBigTexFile.xdv"
```

This does not throw the out of memory error and the PDF files are correct, but my bookmarks are lost. They appear in the first file (MyBigTexFilePart1.pdf) but not in the second (MyBigTexFilePart2.pdf).

I really need to generate a single PDF file with a single execution of xdvipdfmx  in order to keep the bookmarks.

The previous out of memory error is thrown in a computer with Windows 10, using the prompt. I tried now again in a Linux system (and a different computer) and the memory error is not thrown. So it might be something related to the system configuration.

Is there any way to increase the memory available to xdvipdfmx? I think there should be more than enough memory in my computer.

I provide some details about my tests with the Windows computer:

Output using -z 0:
    xdvipdfmx:fatal: Out of memory - asked for 9427841 bytes

Output calling xelatex MyBigTeXFile directly:
    xdvipdfmx:fatal: Out of memory - asked for 3349460 bytes
    No output PDF file written.
[7437xelatex.exe: fwrite: Invalid argument

```
xdvipdfmx -s 1-7443 -o MyBigTeXFile.pdf MyBigTeXFile.xdv throws the out of memory error
xdvipdfmx -s 1-7440 -o MyBigTeXFile.pdf MyBigTeXFile.xdv does not throw the out of memory error
```

So the problem seems to appear beyond 7440 pages.

I'm lost. Any idea is welcome.

Thank you very much

Comment: It’s choking on 2 megs? Weird. What OS are you on? Does `ulimit` work?

Comment: Is there a bug in your TeX file that’s eating up infinite memory? Do other files the same size work? What’s the smallest fragment of the input that reproduces this error?

Comment: what happens with `-z 0` ?

Comment: What happens if you call `xelatex MyBigTeXFile` directly?

Comment: I was in a computer with Windows 10, using the prompt. I tried now again in a Linux system (and a different computer) and the memory error is not thrown. So it might be something related to the system configuration. Thank you, I will try your suggestions in the other computer with Windows.

Comment: In my original question I added additional information about my tests with the Windows computer. I'm quite lost, so any idea is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: No error if done with TextWorks, even in Windows! Could this be something related to the Windows command prompt. I tried with Powershell and the out of memory error is also thrown there.

Comment: It seems that the problem is when using TexLive. With the MikTex distribution (used by TextWorks) it seems to be going well so far.